# Are stack and heap variably sized?

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory

In accordance to many sources, `stack` and `heap` are memory regions devided by empty space. As far as I got this, the stack and the heap grow towards each other as the program is running.

Does that mean that the `stack` and the `heap` are both of variable size? If they are, can one of them occupy the same addresses the other occupied during the previous run (suppose the two runs took place at the same memory addresses)?

If they are of variable size, I guess `stack overflow` occurs when the `stack` tries to take what belongs to the `heap`. If not, a `stack bound` is just what it is and placed somewhere in the middle of the initially empty space between the two regions of memory.

**A bit of clarification:** by the *variability of size* here I mean changing of the reserved space. That is, here I imply that if `stack` size is variable, the reserved for it space changes (like when you change size of an array using `realloc`, but that is just for comparison); `stack overflow` is then occurs by the stack hitting some bound, be it another region like `heap` or something else. If it is not variable, the reserved space stays the same, and `stack overflow` is merely caused by running out of the reserved space. And I also wonder if `heap` is variably sized too.

Comment: The architecture you are describing is very simplistic and not really actual for modern (PC) systems, that have virtual memory and can have different memory regions separated by gigabytes of unmapped space, such that there is no way to overflow the stack so it will hit the heap.

Comment: Also many implementation have guard pages between the different regions which is intended to catch any overflow/underflow from one region into the other.

Comment: Ok, but are they of variable size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack must be contiguous in address space. The heap has no such constraint. Anything beyond that depends how a given platform lays out the memory.

If your address space cannot have holes, a simple layout for an embedded device can be: from address n and below is stack (stacks tends to grow down) and from n and above can be used for heap. Static is then some high address and code is in ROM.

Linux and Windows run on platforms with an MMU so have a lot more options with regards memory arrangement.

Comment: Split stacks are possible. The compiler just needs to generate the correct code.

Comment: Not actually what I meant. You mentioned that _stacks tends to grow down_. What is implied by _growth_? Is the amount of reserved space changes in stack or is it just that the size of its used content grows whereas the reserved space stays the same?

Comment: Used content. Reserved space is fixed without OS support.

Comment: @doron so is then `stack overflow` caused by just running out of this reserved space? and is it also fixed for `heap`?

Comment: Yes. Heaps are a bit more flexible but they can also run out of memory and return a null address.